# How are the developers hiding this video endpoint?

Tags: http, request, streaming

I am streaming a video online and I'd like to download it. However, there seems to be some obfuscation being done to prevent users from knowing where the content is originating from. How do I find the host and path/URL of the mp4? [Here](https://www.documentarymania.com/video/They%20Shall%20Not%20Grow%20Old/) is the link.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is the Save Video As... feature available in FireFox by right clicking on the video. It still begs the question, why doesn't the mp4 path not show up in the dev tools?

[image]